# Discard | Done pattern how to correctly implement in conjunction with the Back button?

Tags: android, user-interface

I have been an Android user for more than 3 years already and I am used to enter into a screen (Activity), change some settings and press back. The changes are saved automatically.

Now I am devoping an app and I wanted to use the Discard | Done buttons in the ActionBar. This Activity is a settings Activity so the user changes some stuff and then presses Done. However now I am confused because what should I do if the users presses Back? Should I also save the setting or should I discard them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my mind, keep the "discard" button only, and save the setting when the back button is pressed.

Comment: Yes, this makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: what if i have to type a lot and need to regularly save? do i press back and open the activity again regularly?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Your use case is different, I would have a "save draft", "discard" and "apply" function. I would map the "save draft" to the back button.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the system-back button should offer the same functionality as the `DISCARD` button. The `DONE` button shouldn't be disregarded - it's still common (in apps for mobile or desktop-based) to confirm an action, or actively save/send information in a form.

Removing the `DONE` button as Sporniket suggests means there are two *negative* interactions (both equating to a cancel) and no confirmation to the user of a save action - for me, I'd be wondering what to do to save the information I'd inputted/changed.

Using system-back as the default save action is counter-intuitive; the system-back button navigates backwards through the activity stack - it's associated with an "exit" by common users, not save.

If you do decide to continue with your implementation (`DISCARD` only), then ensure you have some **visual feedback** which allows the user to know that the information has been saved and to help train them (reassure them) that in your app, system-back will save your changes. This could be achieved by using a `Crouton` when the user presses back, which displays a message telling the user that the data has been saved.

-- Edit:

I should add that my above recommendations are appropriate where the `DISCARD/DONE` pattern is appropriate. You mentioned in your question that you're used to changing settings, and pressing back, having it save your changes automatically, and I would suppose that these are areas which are predominantly toggles, rather than content that's being edited.

Roman Nurik's post ***[here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RomanNurik/posts/R49wVvcDoEW)*** offers more guidelines, and even mentions a way in which `system-back` saves information by default. In this instance, he describes having the `DONE` replace the `up` affordance, and to hide the `DISCARD` button in the overflow menu, citing the use-case where the user is unlikely to want to discard information. (IMHO, I disagree with him - I think that if there's a visible `DONE` or `Save` action, then `system-back` should discard, for the reasons stated above. That said, at least it's some guidance for the pattern with usage guidelines from one of the proponents of the pattern.)

Overall, I think it's something that could be better answered if you gave more context about the information the user will be editing in this screen.

Comment: It's an options (settings) screen with an EditText and some checkboxes. Since there's an EditText I did implement the DISCARD|DONE in the ActionBar pattern. And system-back also saves poping-up a short Toast saying "Options saved".

Comment: How does `system-back` replace a notification?